# A conjecture about strongly regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G \neq K_{v}$ be a $(v,k,\lambda,\mu)$ strongly regular graph. After perusing through [Brouwer's tables of parameter](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab.html)s I have formed the conjecture $$\lambda-\mu \leq \frac{k}{2}.$$

So far I have not been able to prove it, though it seems like an easy statement. Have you seen something like this?

EDIT:

Now that the original claim is proved, we can ask: what is the best possible constant $C$ so that $\lambda-\mu \leq \frac{k}{C}$?

Comment: $G$ should not be complete graph, yes?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, let's exclude it.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a proof now. There is an old result, due originally to Taylor & Levingston, which says that for a strongly regular $G \neq K_{v}$:

$$
k \geq 2\lambda+3-\mu.
$$

It can be found on page 7 of the [BCN book](http://books.google.co.il/books/about/Distance_regular_graphs.html?id=CkgfAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) and in fact holds for a more general class (the so-called amply regular graphs) as pointed out by Neumaier.

Now we can prove the claim in the question by considering two cases:

(I) $\lambda \leq \frac{k}{2}$. Then $\lambda-\mu \leq \lambda \leq \frac{k}{2}$.

(II) $\lambda>\frac{k}{2}$. Then $\lambda-\mu \leq (k-\lambda)-3<k-\lambda<\frac{k}{2}$.

QED

Comment: Or without cases $k\geq 2\lambda+3-\nu>2\lambda-2\nu$.